# how to .writerow() to only 1 row in csv file?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, csv

Currently in my code it changes the 3rd row but for all rows, I want it to only change the row with the entered `GTIN` by the user.

Current code:

```
file=open("stock.csv")
stockfile= csv.reader(file)
for line in stockfile:
    if GTIN in line:
        currentstock= line[2]
        targetstock = line[3]
        newstock = (int(currentstock) - int(Quantity))
        currentstock = str(currentstock)
        targetstock = str(targetstock)
        newstock = str(newstock)
    if newstock < targetstock :
        import csv
        reader = csv.reader(open('stock.csv',"r"))
        new = csv.writer(open('out.csv',"w"))
        for line in reader:
            new.writerow([line[0], line[1], newstock , line[3]])
```

Output in file (it changes all numbers in 3rd column):

```
86947367,banana,1,40
78364721,apple,1,20
35619833,orange,1,30
84716491,sweets,1,90
46389121,chicken,1,10
```

How can I only change the row with the `GTIN` the user enters?

Answer (score 1):

use the `csv` module:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

It has a `csv.reader()` and `csv.writer()`.  Read the file into memory, iterate over it doing calcs/replacements, then write each row to a new list.  Finally, generate a new data file to replace the old one.

Comment: I do not know how to replace in a csv file , can you help with that ?

Comment: @NeedHelppls ,  you don't replace anything in the csv file itself... you create a list representing values in rows as you read the csv input... then replace values with new ones using simple assignment.  Then write that new list to a file, replacing the old file.

Comment: @NeedHelppls you would access the file exactly twice... once to read the input and once to write the output at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I answered one of your other questions before you were using csvreader but it looks like it got deleted. But the principle is the same. As I stated in one of the comments, I don't think you should keep reopening/rereading `stock.txt`. Just read it line by line then write line by line to an output file:

```
stock_number = input('Enter the stock number: ')
new_item = input('Enter item to add to above stock listing: ')

lines = []
with open('stock.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        lines.append(line)

# can call this 'output.txt' if you don't want to overwrite original        
with open('stock.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        if stock_number in line:
            # strip newline, add new item, add newline
            line = '{},{}\n'.format(line.strip(), new_item)
        outfile.write(line)
```

Edit: here it is with `csv` module instead. This makes it a little more straightforward because the `csv` module gives you a list of strings for each line, then you can add to or modify them as desired. Then you can just write the list back line by line, without worrying about newlines or delimiters.

```
import csv

stock_number = input('Enter the stock number: ')
new_item = input('Enter item to add to above stock listing: ')
lines = []
with open('stock.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in csv.reader(infile):
        lines.append(line)

# change this to 'stock.txt' to overwrite original file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in lines:
        if stock_number in line:
            line.append(new_item)
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Also you shouldn't really `import` anything in the middle of the code like that. Imports generally go at the top of your file.

Comment: what about the calc where do they go ?

Comment: @NeedHelppls what clac? What do you mean? Have you run the code above? Works perfectly for me.